# why is na.rm not working for this case only?

Tags: r

I have been working with weather data that does contain some NA values. Usually to sum up values for one day I use colSums like the following.`colSums(df,na.rm = T)`. This ofcourse never created any issue.
However using the same now for a different analysis is returning the following error.

```
colSums(I_2011,na.rm=T)
Error in colSums(I_2011, na.rm = T) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I don't understand why. the only difference is I_2011 is imported from a csv

```
I_2011<-read.csv("2011_IMD.csv",check.names = FALSE)
```

does the latter require something different?

lost on what to do next. I don't need to remove the columns containing NA. only to disregard them while doing colsums .
tried `

```
I_2011 %>% 
  mutate(avg= rowSums(., na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  bind_cols(I_2011[setdiff(names(I_2011), names(.))] , .)
```

returns the same error.

Comment: Hey @CovetTachi, as the error states, one or more of your columns isn't numeric and so, it isn't possible to sum numerics with non-numerics. You'll have to catch which column(s) isn't parsed as a numeric

Comment: If you use a function like `str(I_2011)` you will probably see that one of your columns is not numeric.

Comment: @Bart. this never occurred to me as running this over other df came without any problems. PS. I used `I_2011 <- as.data.frame(sapply(I_2011, as.numeric))` to convert and summed it up. It gives me the desired output but should I be worried about the warning message "In lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion"?

Comment: There were probably some actual strings in your dataframe, that couldn't be converted to numeric and so were changed to NA. You could try to check which columns were strings and compare them to their numeric versions and filter the NA rows to see those strings

Comment: @CovetTachi Its probably worth figuring out where the non numeric values come from. The warning you get is because `as.numeric` fails on the conversion for specific values e.g.: `as.numeric("a")`